# Network related error 40 and error 53 of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was trying to access to another database in the same local server at my office. I have provided credentials correctly but it was showing the following error

[Error 40 and 53 etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxl1C.png)

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your TCP/IP port is enabled:

1. Click on SQL Server Configuration Manager from the start menu and
   click yes on the dialogue box
2. In the opened screen expand SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration and
   there     click on ‘Client Protocols
3. Check if TCP/IP option is kept enabled in the right section of the
   window. If it isn’t right click on TCP/IP and click on ‘Enabled’
4. Now from the left section of the window expand “SQL Server Network
   Configuration” and under that click on “Protocols for SQLEXPRESS”
5. Check if TCP/IP is kept “Enabled” and if not then make it Enabled as
   step 3
6. Right click on TCP/IP and click on properties.
7. From the IP Address tab, scroll and under IPAll section check if TCP
   port contains value “1433”. If it is blank then provide 1433 and
   click “OK”

Note: Please make sure if TCP port of the desired PC also contains the same value i.e. 1433

For more info or if you face any windows firewall related problems regarding this you can see the solutions with screenshots in my blog.
shadmanjahangir.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks, it works. Windows firewall issue was also well described in your blog.